# Python package build does not update code

Tags: python, build

I've set up a python package for distribution and in the past it has always successfully build.
The basic structure of the package is as such:

```
package  
|--folder 1  
     |--init  
|--folder 2  
     |--init  
setup.py  
LICENSE.txt  
MANIFEST.txt
```

Lately I have noticed that the package "remembers" old code. It does not completely update the latest modules and codes. In the case where folder 1 was completely removed (also all references to it, imports in inits) and folder 3 created, folder 1 still gets built into the new package. Some python files also do not update where as others update successfully with the new build.

I currently use `__all__ = []` in the inits instead of imports (I highly doubt that this is causing the issues since a build (as I understand it) only requires the `__init__` python file in each directory.

How would one go about completely dumping the "memory" of the previously built packages?

**EDIT**

I did look at the egg info as well as the output of the package build. The build itself seems to be creating all the correct files/folders.

I have tried uninstalling the package with pip using its name `pip uninstall package` as well as `pip uninstall package.2.0.0.whl` before installing the package again. Installing from scratch in a new virtual environment also yields the same results.

Comment: how are you building your package?

Comment: Im building the package using the setup.py file with the command `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` Some settings in setup.py are:

name=package_name
version=2.0.0 (Ive updated this as well in an attempt)
include_package_data = True

The additional items such as package discription, requirements, url are all included. Its set up using setuptools

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the issue was caused by the build folder in my python package (which gets created when the package is built). I removed this file completely (as it seems like it did not properly override), saved the entire directory as a local copy (removed from the git folder) and rebuilt. All the old "memory" was completely rebuilt and the package is deploying correctly